# Creating a `RAM` chip in `Verilog` with single in/out data port

Tags: verilog

I want to create a `RAM` chip in verilog to learn how `Verilog`, modern chips like `RAM` and `EEPROM` allow reading and writing to the chip over a single address port and a single data port.(Data port being the input and output port)
I want to do the same thing in `Verilog`, and I think I need the inout type, but I don't know how it works.
I google it, but all `RAM` examples I can find have a separate data write and data read port.
Since the inout type requires both sides to be connected to a wire, I need to connect one wire from one side to a reg chosen by the address.(so no assign).But I don't know how to do that.

This is what I tried and doesn't work:

```
wire [7:0] a;
wire rw;// 0 if read, 1 if write
reg [7:0] mem [16];
initial begin
  if (rw == 1) begin
    #1 a = mem[0];// 0 would be the address wire, but excluding it for clarity
  end
  if (rw == 0) begin
    #1 mem[0] = a;// 0 would be the address wire, but excluding it for clarity
  end
end
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> all RAM examples I can find have a separate data write and data read port.

The reason is a combination of two facts:

1. A true bi-directional data bus would requires tri-state drivers.
2. FPGA or ASIC chips no longer have on-chip tri-state drivers.

The only place where a bi-directional data is possible is at I/O where you have tri-state pads.

Thus internally everybody will use the two data buses as **any real memory** will have at its core a separate read-data and write-data bus. Then at the edge (at the pads) they will switch to bi-directional mode.

To write your own Verilog bi-directional bus you should use tri-state signal assignments. Something along the line of:

```
inout[7:0] data_bus,

// This assignment is inside the memory model:
// Driving the read data out of the memory device
assign data_bus = mem_read ? mem_read_data : 8'hzz;


// This assignment is outside the memory model
// Driving the write data into the memory device
assign data_bus = mem_read ? 8'hzz : external_driver;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if FPGA's no longer have on-chip tri-state drivers, then how can I test my bus. Currently, I use edaplayground to write and test my stuff as I'm waiting for my FPGA to arrive, and it has a verilog thing for a testbed. I use it to test all featuress of my "cpu". If there are no on-chip tri-state drivers, then how can I test my bidirectional ram bus? Or is it not a limitation on simulators?

Comment: No, it is not it not a limitation on simulators.